# Lucene Module in Orchard CMS has error

Tags: search, indexing, lucene, orchardcms

I am using Orchard CMS. I Use search,Index and Lucene module.The search module didn't work after 2weeks.I had to uninstall this module. Now I have this error on my page

```
You need to enable an index implementation module like Lucene.
```

All of this module are now enable.How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Re-enable the Lucene module

Comment: I have re-enable and disable this module.but this error is shown

Comment: Which version of orchard are you using right now / which branch are you on? I cannot replicate this issue with 1.10 and dev

Comment: I am using the 1.9 of orchard cms.

Comment: Any errors in the logs when you try to enable the module? Did you by any chance install a different version than the one that came with Orchard?